# If functions defined inside the class body go automatically to the prototype object, why do I get: TypeError: obj.__proto__.drive is not a function?

Tags: javascript

If functions defined inside the class body go automatically to the prototype object, why do I get: `TypeError: obj.__proto__.drive is not a function`?

```
class Car {
  constructor(name, year) {
    this.name = name;
    this.year = year;
  }

  //this is what's happening under the hood 
  // Car.prototype.drive = function(){..}
   drive = function(){
       console.log("driving")
  }
 }

 const obj = new Car("toyota", "1996")

 obj.__proto__.drive()
```

Comment: You're declaring `drive` as a class field (ie: `dirve = ...`), not as a method (ie: `drive(){ ... }`). Class fields are added to the instance and to the prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment you should use `method syntax` to define a function in a class' prototype:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions

```js
class Car {
  constructor(name, year) {
    this.name = name;
    this.year = year;
  }

  //this is what's happening under the hood 
  // Car.prototype.drive = function(){..}
   drive(){
       console.log("driving")
  }
 }

 const obj = new Car("toyota", "1996")

 obj.__proto__.drive()
```